# WEB3.JS problem

Tags: web3js

I am trying to use the library “ethereumjs-tx” but it does not work.
I get this error message: “TypeError: Tx is not a constructor” on the code “const tx = new Tx(txObject)”.

Here is my code:

```
const Tx = require(‘ethereumjs-tx’)

const txObject = {

    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),

    to: account2,

    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.3', 'ether')),

    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000), 

    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))

}

const tx = new Tx(txObject)
```

Thank you for your help

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

It's `const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction` .

Here is the exemple from the Github repository : https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx .